# JSP - How to write a valid search form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, netbeans

I have a problem with a search form in a JSP project. In particular an user can subscribe to an event and the admin must be able to search all the members of that event.

I write a form like this:

```
out.println("<fieldset><legend>Search</legend><form action=\"cercaIscritti.jsp\" method=\"post\">"
            + "Name: <input name=\"name\" type=\"text\"><br>Surname: <input name=\"surname\" type=\"text\"><br>"
            + "Belonging: <input name=\"belonging\" type=\"text\"><br>Countr: <input name=\"country\" type=\"text\"><br>"
            + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Cerca\"></fieldset></form>");
```

(If it isn't readable: there are four `<input>`, one for each column in the table `user` and a `<input>` for submit).

I would like all the fields to be optional so that the admin can fill what it wants, but how do I build the query?

I tried something like this :

```
public ResultSet searchSubs(String name, String surname, String belonging, String country) {
    try {
        boolean n = false, s = false, b = false, c = false;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ";
        if (!isEmpty(name)) {
            query += "firstName = ?";
            n = true;
        }
        if (!isEmpty(surname)) {
            if (n) {
                query += " AND lastName = ?";
            } else {
                query += "lastName = ?";
            }
            s = true;
        }
        if (!isEmpty(belonging)) {
            if (n || s) {
                query += " AND belonging = ?";
            } else {
                query += "belonging = ?";
            }
            b = true;
        }//and go on
```

But how can I add the values with the `PreparedStatement`? Is this the correct way? If it's not, how can I do something like that?

The booleans are there in the middle only for test, I thought I would use them in some way but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can follow to search with multiples values :

```
public ResultSet searchSubs(String name, String surname, String belonging, String country){
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1";
        //---------------------------------------^^^
        int index = 1;
        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            query += " AND firstName = ?";
        }
        if (!surname.isEmpty()) {
            query += " AND surname = ?";
        }
        if (!belonging.isEmpty()) {
            query += " AND belonging = ?";
        }

        if (!country.isEmpty()) {
            query += " AND country = ?";
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            ps.setString(index++, name);
        }
        if (!surname.isEmpty()) {
            ps.setString(index++, surname);
        }
        if (!belonging.isEmpty()) {
            ps.setString(index++, belonging);
        }
        if (!country.isEmpty()) {
            ps.setString(index++, country);
        }

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        //...
```

The idea is simple :

- In the Where clause use `1=1` to not get an error if the user not enter any value(in this case your query is `SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1` and it will return every thing)
- The first part if to fill the query with the non empty fields
- The second if to fill the prepared statement with the right values.
- finally execute the prepared statement and get the results.

Comment: For first, thanks! This is what I was looking for! **But** the IDE return this: "Unknown column 'surname' in 'where clause'". Why? P.S.: I think that index should start from 1 and not 0

Comment: You are welcome @tuzzo, did you check the names of column of your table, you have to use the right names and yes the index should start from 1 i edit it 9min before your comment :)

Comment: You're right. In the db the column is not 'surname', it's 'lastName'. Now it works, thank you!